# How to make matplotlib/pcolor show the last row and column of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

matplotlib/pcolor chops off the last row and column of data. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549195/matplotlib-pcolor-does-not-plot-last-row-and-column) suggests that increasing the dimensions of x and y arguments by one should resolve the problem. Now consider the following simple example:

```
x = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([1,2])
z = np.array([[10,20],[30,40]])

# Using pcolor
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolor(x,y,z,vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())
ax.set_xlim([x.min(),x.max()])
ax.set_ylim([y.min(),y.max()])
cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)

# Using matshow (for comparison)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ms = ax.matshow(z,vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin = 'lower')
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
cb = fig.colorbar(ms, ax=ax)
```

Increasing the dimensions of x and y by one e.g., by changing them to:

```
x = np.array([1,2,2.1])
y = np.array([1,2,2.1])
```

does not solve the issue. How can I make the pcolor plot to look similar to matshow plot?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([1,2,3])
z = np.array([[10,20],[30,40]])

# Using pcolor
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolor(x,y,z,vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())
ax.set_xlim([x.min(),x.max()])
ax.set_ylim([y.min(),y.max()])
cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Edit:

```
x = np.array([0.5,1.5,2.5])
y = np.array([0.5,1.5,2.5])
z = np.array([[10,20],[30,40]])

# Using pcolor
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolor(x,y,z,vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())
ax.set_xticks([1., 2.])
ax.set_yticks([1., 2.])
cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This looks good but the problem is that it shows that x and y range from 1 to 3 while actual x and y are 1 and 2 and this could be quite misleading. Is there any way to put the ticks and tick labels (1 and 2) in the middle of each rectangle?

Comment: you have to modify the axes and the ticks, see the edit in my answer

Comment: The resulting plot is exactly what I was looking for. However, here you have manipulated the original x and y in such a way that it works for this particular example. Is there a more general recipe that works for any x and y (i.e., to get the original x and y and then modifies them in such a way that the graph looks like what you did for this particular example)? A more general procedure will take into account that the entries of x and y may not be always evenly spaced.