# missing row of data in raster plot when overplotting contours with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster

This question is closely related to the this one :

[Matplotlib: pcolor() does not plot last row and column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549195/matplotlib-pcolor-does-not-plot-last-row-and-column)

I want a raster plot of hourly data, labled on the y axis from 0 to 24.  Having the time vector as the same size as the data array caused me to miss a row of data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.random.uniform(size=(24,10))  # dummy data

times=np.arange(24)
xnum=np.arange(10)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
img=ax.pcolormesh(xnum,times,x,cmap='seismic',
        rasterized=False)
```

Giving me this:

[image: first plot]

with the last hour missing. Then I found the solution from the posting above, which was to add 1 to the time array.  I want lables every 2 hours, so I also change that:

```
times=np.arange(25) # NOTE ONE MORE THAN DATA SIZE
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
img=ax.pcolormesh(xnum,times,x,cmap='seismic',
        rasterized=False)
yticki=2
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min(times), max(times)+yticki,yticki))
```

[image]

Great, that seems to work.  But now I want to add contours.  If I do this with **times=np.arange(24)**, then I can add contours like this

```
cont_levs=[-0.5,0.5]
cs=ax.contour(xnum,times,x,cont_levs, colors='k')
```

and I get this:

[image]

But my top row is missing again...

However, if I try this with

```
times=np.arange(25)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: Length of y must be number of rows in z.

I can get the lables correct AND contours over the top by restricting the y vector to be 0-23:

```
cs=ax.contour(xnum,times[:-1],x,cont_levs, colors='k')
```

This give me this plot:

[image]

So now I have the correct yticks, AND 24 raster boxes, AND contours over the top, BUT the contours only go to time=23, which makes me think that they are either "squashed" and thus wrong, or are at least missing the last hour.

i can shift the contours up so that they start at t=0.5 and end at t=23.5 by doing this:

```
cs=ax.contour(xnum,times[:-1]+0.5,x,cont_levs, colors='k')
```

but is there a way to keep all 24 rows of data in the raster plot, with correcting y labling AND also overplot contours going right from the bottom t=0 to the top (t=24) of the plot?